# Java Redirecting Input and Output Stream of Terminal to GUI (JSch)

Tags: java, shell, ssh, terminal, jsch

I'm working on a project in which I intend to make a Java GUI application that connects to a ssh server and executes remote commands on the server. I'm willing to use JSch Library. My aim is to make buttons and textfields those will provide the user the ability of sending commands and getting replies easily. I mean, instead of opening xShell and prompting "grep "hi" /usr/file.txt", the user will choose the path from the list and will enter "hi" into the textfield and will press the button for grep.

Problem is, I couldn't find a solution to redirect inputstream so that i could send the arguments those shall be taken from related GUI components.

Since I have not made so much modifications on the JSch's example code, yet, you can see the code here: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html

Thanks from now on.

Comment: Any update on this??