# Java ssh (jsch) set stream to UI instead of console

Tags: java, user-interface, ssh, jsch

I have a java program that uses the following lines to send ssh input/output to the console window.

```
channel.setInputStream(System.in);
channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
```

How might I acheive this using a UI instead of the console. For example, I have a UI with `JTextPane panelOutput` and `JTextPane panelInput`.

Same question as this person (unanswered):
[Java Redirecting Input and Output Stream of Terminal to GUI (JSch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485164/java-redirecting-input-and-output-stream-of-terminal-to-gui-jsch)

Also, Is there an existing open source java program that does this already?

Answer (score 0):

This site has a java ssh UI download:

http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/

In the zip, it is the file: SwingShell.java